# Estimation of coefficient of power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. As we know this function can be represented as power series
$$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.$$ Let $$M(r):=\max_{|z|=r}|F(z)|.$$ I am trying to estimate the coefficient $a_n$ for $n\to\infty$ using the function $M(r)$. Since $F$ in entire we have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=0,$$
or equivalently
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln |a_n|}{n}=-\infty.$$ From here I don't know where else to go to find a connection to $M(r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cauchy integral formula,
$$ a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}\;dz $$
Therefore
$$ |a_n|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|F(re^{i\theta})|r^{-n}\;d\theta\leq\frac{M(r)}{r^n} $$

Comment: I think you forgot the modulus

Comment: Good point, I did.