# Prove a certain holomorphic function does not exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Prove that there does not exist a holomorphic function f(z) on any open set containing 0 such that $f^{(n)}(0) = n^n\cdot n!$

I tried to use the Cauchy integral formula for higher derivatives and proved by contradiction, but had no progress. Could someone give some insights on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The Cauchy integral formula quickly leads to an upper bound on $|f^{(n)}(0)|$, see for instance this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672760/estimation-of-coefficient-of-power-series/1672765#1672765

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose there were such an $f.$ Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n
$$

has positive radius of convergence.